# Cherrypy appears to be adding the letter "i" to the request path

Tags: python, apache, .htaccess, cherrypy

I am currently running a CherryPy application as a CGI using the following configuration:

In Apache config:

```
# snip

ScriptAlias /myproject.cgi /var/www/mywebsite/myproject.cgi
<Directory /var/www/mywebsite>
    Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews +ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

In the `/var/www/mywebsite/.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^acoolproject/?$ myproject.cgi [L]
RewriteRule ^acoolproject/(.*)$ myproject.cgi/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

The double redirect in Apache may seem redundant but it is there for a reason.

In `/var/www/mywebsite/myproject.cgi`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import sys

import cgi
import cgitb
import wsgiref.handlers

import main

cgitb.enable()

def application(env, start_response):
    app = cherrypy.tree.mount(main.Main(), "/acoolproject", config=cherrypy_config)
    return app(env, start_response)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    wsgiref.handlers.CGIHandler().run(application)
```

And in my main application, `main.py`, amongst other things, I have the following debug information in the `Main.default` method:

```
class Main(object):

    # snip

    def default(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return cherrypy.request.path_info
    default.exposed = True
```

The problem is, when I browse to (or cURL to) "http://mywebsite.com/acoolproject" the debug information outputs the string "i". Because this "i" mysteriously appears, the requests are not correctly routed to the write handlers, and everything ends up being handled by the `default` handler.

I've checked all my files for a typo or misspelt URL with an extra "i" and can't find anything. Is there any reason that this is happening?

- **Apache version:** Apache/2.2.22 (Debian)
- **Python version:** Python 2.7.3
- **CherryPy version:** CherryPy 3.3.0

### Update

If I change the path in the htaccess rule and the mount point from `acoolproject` to `proj`, then the output becomes "oject.cgi". So it looks like CherryPy is getting the path of the URL as something like `path_info = url[len(mount_point):]`.

Comment: Your `<Directory>`-directive is the first thing that springs to mind. What you probably want is `<Directory /var/www/mywebsite>`. Also, can you get the `default` handler to output *anything* other than «`i`»? I.e. if you `return "Foo Bar"`, will the text «`Foo Bar`» be returned from the application?

Comment: Oops, that was a typo, fixed. Yes, if I put `return "foo bar"` it returns `foo bar`.